How to save file to secondary external volume on Android 10 without Storage Access Framework?
I need to save files to the root volume directories.
To do this I'm using
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 

permission for old devices and
MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 

for newer ones.
Currently I am able to write files to any volumes on any Android version except for Android 10 (29 SDK). As for this Android version, I am able to write a file to a primary external volume (internal memory) but when I try to save a file to secondary external volume I receive java.io.IOException: Permission denied exception.
Manifest permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

option is set.
Any ideas on how this is to be done without SAF?

You do not have rights to arbitrary locations on removable storage on Android 10 and below. Whether it works or not will depend on how the manufacturer set things up and therefore will vary by device model.

Also requestLegacyExternalStorage doesn't work
